# Why does amazon charge for free tier usage?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, billing

I have an issue with amazon free tier account, I have deployed two EC2 instances (1 linux and 1 windows) on amazon each having 30GB of storage which is permissible under free tier, these instances are continuously running 24/7 so that they are always available,what I don't understand is that starting last month I have had charges to my account for exceeding cloud storage usage that have left me confused.

I have read details on [Free Tier](https://aws.amazon.com/free) more than 5 times but I still can't understand what I'm doing wrong, checked the Cost Explorer, the only thing that comes to mind is perhaps the 30GB is applied universally for all instances but I am not sure as I don't know how my account usage is calculated. I have tried contacting support assistant but I am yet to receive any response from them.

I would really appreciate if someone helped set some things straight because I have hit a wall with this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My free tier account uses 30ish GB for in a VM, and I am getting a warning that I am approaching the GB limit (which I am), since day one.

For me, although I'm not a native speaker, the  [description](https://aws.amazon.com/free/?awsf.Free%20Tier%20Types=categories%2312monthsfree) ...

```
STORAGE & CONTENT DELIVERY   
Amazon Elastic Block Storage
30 GB

any combination of General Purpose (SSD) or Magnetic

Persistent, durable, low-latency block-level storage volumes for EC2 
instances
```

...also seems pretty straightforward: 30 GB for your volumes for your instances. 
Summed up, not "per".

Comment: Thanks, I guess this has to be the case because I cant find any other explanation for this

Answer (score 1):

There is no EC2 under always free tier, only under 12 months free tier.

Comment: Yes I know, sorry if I was unclear, I am currently 3 months in (using the 1 year free trial) that's why i am surprised I have started accumulating costs this early

Comment: I guess 30GB is overall EBS under free tier, but then it's not clear, why you weren't charged for the first months.